# how can i store a node before deleting it in a linkedlist in java?

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I'am trying to store the node that I want to delete it in another linked list so I can print the information about the deleted node before I completely delete the node 
how can I store the wanted node in another linkedlist?
I started checking if the id exists in the linked list so I can show the data of the existed node and store it in another linked list to print the data of the deleted node , i can not make a new object because i don't think it will recognize the node and it will make a whole new node
any ideas?

here is the code i tried so far

```
 System.out.println("1- Remove student by his/her ID\n" +
    "2- Remove students that have not to complete the minimum requirement");
                int cho=input.nextInt();
           switch(cho){
               case 1:
                   System.out.print("Please enter the student ID that you would like to remove:"); 
                   String id=input.next();
                   if(list.check_std(id)==false){//checking if it does exist
                   SeniorProjectSystem deletelist=new SeniorProjectSystem(); 
                  //the new linked list
//i stopped here
                   }
                   break;
               case 2:
             //did not done this yet      break;
           }
```

the expected output is attached in a photo[the expected out put the schedule is the node data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhUyG.png)

update:
i did the remove coding but the problem is in storing the deleted object since you all helped me i tried to make a method to store the object and print it but it did not work very well it prints the whole objects  (deleted an non deleted ones)
here is a method foe]r deleting an object in my link list class:

```
public void RemoveStudent(String id){
       stuhead = RemoveStudentID(stuhead,id);

   }
   private Student RemoveStudentID(Student s, String id){
       if (!isStuEmpty()) {
            // IF the first node (at the head) has the data value we are wanting to delete
            // we found it. Delete by skipping the node and making head point to the next node.
            if (stuhead.getStudentID().equals(id)) {
                stuhead = stuhead.getNext();
            }
                            else {
                                    Student helpPtr = stuhead;
                // Traverse to correct deletion point
                while (helpPtr.getNext() != null) {
                    if (helpPtr.getNext().getStudentID().equals(id)) {
                        helpPtr.setNext(helpPtr.getNext().getNext());
                        break;                      }
                    helpPtr = helpPtr.getNext();
                }

             printDeletedStu(helpPtr);}
                            return stuhead;
        }
        return stuhead;
    }

    public void printDeletedStu(Student s){
    String.format(s.getStudentID()," ",s.getResearch_intrest()," ",s.getTopic()," ",s.getCourse()," ",s.isApproval()," ",s.getSupervisorID());



    }
```

here is the output:

```
1.Add a new student.
2.Print supervisor list.
3.Print student list. 
4. Add research topic.
5.Remove student.
6.Print senior project list in ascending order 
7."Exit.
Enter your choice:  5
1- Remove student by his/her ID
2- Remove students that have not to complete the minimum requirement
1
Please enter the student ID that you would like to remove:1777
Student ID          ,Research interest   ,Suggsted topic                                                               ,courses             ,Approval            ,SupervisorID        
1723                ,Asma                ,artificial intelligent,How the machine thinks: intelligent learning      ,[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]       ,true                        ,00023                         
1743                ,Roaa                ,artificial intelligent,                                                  ,[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]       ,false                       ,0                             
1003                ,Sara                ,network             ,                                                  ,[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]       ,false                       ,00013                         
1777                ,Rania               ,database            ,                                                  ,[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]       ,false                       ,0                             

deleted
1.Add a new student.
2.Print supervisor list.
3.Print student list. 
4. Add research topic.
5.Remove student.
6.Print senior project list in ascending order 
7."Exit.
Enter your choice:  3
Student ID          ,Research interest   ,Suggsted topic                                                               ,courses             ,Approval            ,SupervisorID        
1723                ,Asma                ,artificial intelligent,How the machine thinks: intelligent learning      ,[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]       ,true                        ,00023                         
1743                ,Roaa                ,artificial intelligent,                                                  ,[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]       ,false                       ,0                             
1003                ,Sara                ,network             ,                                                  ,[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]       ,false                       ,00013                         

1.Add a new student.
2.Print supervisor list.
3.Print student list. 
4. Add research topic.
5.Remove student.
6.Print senior project list in ascending order 
7."Exit.
Enter your choice:  7
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 33 seconds)
```

Comment: Just add the reference to the new list--what's the specific issue?

Comment: i didn't get you, you mean using next()?

Comment: why can't you just print the information of the Node you want to delete before actually deleting it? Is it necessary to store it in another list?

Comment: Your collection has objects. You somehow can get a reference to that object, e.g., `Node someObj = list.find(whatever)` (or perhaps your `delete` returns the object that was deleted). `otherList.add(someObj)` is all you need to do.

Comment: It should be noted that removing an item from a collection in Java doesn't 'delete' the object. 

Garbage collection will only delete objects that no longer have a reference to them. 

In your case if you grab an item from the list to delete, print it to the screen, and then remove it from the list (as mentioned above) garbage collection will eventually delete that object. 
If you want to keep that object you are removing from the list, for whatever reason, simply add it to another list. 

https://www.baeldung.com/jvm-garbage-collectors

Is that what you're looking for clarity on?

Comment: I vote in favor of the removal function returning the removed item. Then you simply grab that returned object and print whatever info / do whatever you want about it.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, here's how we delete a node in a linked list:

```
do:
  find B // which is to-be-deleted
Start:
A -> B -> C

do:
  A.next = B.next

Result:
A -> C
```

Clearly, at this point, we still have a reference to B (otherwise, `B.next` isn't even a thing). Since `B` is the deleted node, just add it to the other linked list:

```
linked-list deletedNodes = ...;
do:
  deletedNodes.append(B);
```

Comment: Pseudocode, since your posted code doesn't make it entirely clear how your linked list is being implemented